# Fix NULL Date Column?

Tags: sql, join, left-join

My query:

```
SELECT
  a.GtrReference, a.SourceWarehouse, a.TargetWarehouse, /*a.DateCreated,*/ 
  d.ExpectedDueDate, a.EntryType, a.ControlAccount, a.InitialValue,
  a.ValRecToDate, a.Operator, b.Description, c.Description,
  Convert(decimal(14,2), 
  (a.InitialValue - a.ValRecToDate)) as RemainingValue 
FROM [GtrMaster] a WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN [InvWhControl] b WITH (NOLOCK) 
  ON (a.SourceWarehouse = b.Warehouse) 
LEFT JOIN [InvWhControl] c WITH (NOLOCK) 
  ON (a.TargetWarehouse = c.Warehouse) 
LEFT JOIN [GtrDetail] d WITH (NOLOCK) 
  ON (a.GtrReference = d.GtrReference and a.InitialValue = d.InitialValue) 
WHERE ( a.EntryType = 'W' OR a.EntryType = 'S' ) 
  AND a.Complete <> 'Y' AND a.GtrReference >= '' 
ORDER BY a.GtrReference
```

What I get:

| GtrReference | SourceWarehouse | TargetWarehouse | ExpectedDueDate | EntryType | ControlAccount | InitialValue | ValRecToDate | Operator | Description | Description | RemainingValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02022023 | W | 01 | NULL | W | 1610 | 3616.00 | 0.00 | CWHITE | IN TRANSIT WAREHOUSE | MAIN WAREHOUSE | 3616.00 |
| 202212-019 | W | 01 | NULL | W | 1610 | 25365.40 | 0.00 | ahsiao | IN TRANSIT WAREHOUSE | MAIN WAREHOUSE | 25365.40 |
| 202301-014 | W | 01 | 2023-03-08 00:00:00.000 | W | 1610 | 20680.00 | 0.00 | ahsiao | IN TRANSIT WAREHOUSE | MAIN WAREHOUSE | 20680.00 |

I'm trying to see ExpectedDueDate from the GtrDetail table, but it's NULL. It has to do with my join. How do I fix it?

What I want to see:

| GtrReference | SourceWarehouse | TargetWarehouse | ExpectedDueDate | EntryType | ControlAccount | InitialValue | ValRecToDate | Operator | Description | Description | RemainingValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02022023 | W | 01 | 2023-02-17 00:00:00.000 | W | 1610 | 3616.00 | 0.00 | CWHITE | IN TRANSIT WAREHOUSE | MAIN WAREHOUSE | 3616.00 |
| 202212-019 | W | 01 | 2023-02-15 00:00:00.000 | W | 1610 | 25365.40 | 0.00 | ahsiao | IN TRANSIT WAREHOUSE | MAIN WAREHOUSE | 25365.40 |
| 202301-014 | W | 01 | 2023-03-08 00:00:00.000 | W | 1610 | 20680.00 | 0.00 | ahsiao | IN TRANSIT WAREHOUSE | MAIN WAREHOUSE | 20680.00 |

The GtrDetail table picks up each GIT, and there are multiple. I need it to just pick ONE, or else I get a ton of duplicate entries instead of the 3 I need.

For example, the GtrDetail table has this for the expectedduedate entry. I only need one of them (any one of them per GtrReference).

| GtrReference | ExpectedDueDate |
| --- | --- |
| 02022023 | 2023-02-17 00:00:00.000 |
| 02022023 | 2023-02-17 00:00:00.000 |
| 202212-019 | 2023-02-15 00:00:00.000 |
| 202212-019 | 2023-02-15 00:00:00.000 |
| 202301-014 | 2023-03-08 00:00:00.000 |

Sample GtrMaster

| GtrReference | SourceWarehouse | TargetWarehouse | EntryType | NextLine | ControlAccount | InitialValue | ValRecToDate | DateCreated | TimeCreatedHh | TimeCreatedMm | Operator | Complete | InterfaceFlag | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02022023 | W | 01 | W | 3 | 1610 | 3616.00 | 0.00 | 2023-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 9 | 13 | CWHITE | 0x00000000AC2AAC0E |  |  |
| 202212-019 | W | 01 | W | 3 | 1610 | 25365.40 | 0.00 | 2022-12-15 00:00:00.000 | 11 | 37 | ahsiao | 0x00000000A8109E62 |  |  |
| 202301-014 | W | 01 | W | 2 | 1610 | 20680.00 | 0.00 | 2023-01-06 00:00:00.000 | 8 | 39 | ahsiao | 0x00000000A9B92FB6 |  |  |

Sample GtrDetail

| GtrReference | SourceWarehouse | TargetWarehouse | Line | StockCode | TransfCompPeriod | TransfCompYear | GtrQuantity | QtyReceived | InitialValue | ValueReceivedSrc | UnitCost | CostUom | ValueReceivedTgt | ProductClass | Branch | Area | SalesOrder | SalesOrderLine | DeliveryNote | Invoice | TransfDocNum | TransactionDate | ExpectedDueDate | TransferComplete | LockFlag | NextEntry | Version | Release | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02022023 | W | 01 | 1 | RNHT-M8 BODY | 0 | 0 | 265.000000 | 0.000000 | 1696.00 | 0.00 | 6.40000 | EA | 0.00 | FMAN | 0 | 2023-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 2023-02-17 00:00:00.000 | Y | 2 | 0x00000000AC78C0D5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 02022023 | W | 01 | 2 | RNHT-M10 BODY | 0 | 0 | 300.000000 | 0.000000 | 1920.00 | 0.00 | 6.40000 | EA | 0.00 | FMAN | 0 | 2023-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 2023-02-17 00:00:00.000 | Y | 2 | 0x00000000AC78C0D6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 202212-019 | W | 01 | 1 | SH-60-043 RM | 0 | 0 | 18000.000000 | 0.000000 | 8069.40 | 0.00 | 0.44830 | EA | 0.00 | BITA | 0 | 2022-12-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-02-15 00:00:00.000 | Y | 2 | 0x00000000AC78C0D7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 202212-019 | W | 01 | 2 | SH-60-081 | 0 | 0 | 92000.000000 | 0.000000 | 17296.00 | 0.00 | 0.18800 | EA | 0.00 | BITA | 0 | 2022-12-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-02-15 00:00:00.000 | Y | 2 | 0x00000000AC78C0D8 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 202301-014 | W | 01 | 1 | SH-60-081 | 0 | 0 | 110000.000000 | 0.000000 | 20680.00 | 0.00 | 0.18800 | EA | 0.00 | BITA | 0 | 2023-01-06 00:00:00.000 | 2023-03-08 00:00:00.000 | Y | 2 | 0x00000000AC78C0D9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Tinitialvalue in GtrMaster is a summation of the initialvalues in GtrDetail for each GtrReference.

Comment: It's pretty clear that you have `GtrReference`\`InitialValue` records in your `GtrMaster` table that are NOT present in your `GtrDetail` table. When that situation occurs, what expectedDueDate would want. this is entirely the behavior one would expect from a LEFT OUTER JOIN. To help us guide better, please share sample data from `gtrmaster` and `gtrdetail` and expected results when `LEFT OUTER JOIN`ing those two tables together.

Comment: So sorry for the wait. I'm surprised someone else hasn't popped in here to answer or ask more questions. It's been a very busy day for me. Since `initialValue` isn't viable as a join condition (since master is a summation of detail), can you drop that from your `ON` clause and rerun? I suspect the date will show up like you are needing. If that ends up ballooning the records, then likely you just need a subqeury on your details table to join to instead (if that makes sense).

Comment: @Jnevill can you guide me through this?

Answer (score 0):

So sorry for the wait. First step is just to remove that `initialValue` from your join condition and see if, given your data, that solves the issue:

```
SELECT
  a.GtrReference, a.SourceWarehouse, a.TargetWarehouse, /*a.DateCreated,*/ 
  d.ExpectedDueDate, a.EntryType, a.ControlAccount, a.InitialValue,
  a.ValRecToDate, a.Operator, b.Description, c.Description,
  Convert(decimal(14,2), 
  (a.InitialValue - a.ValRecToDate)) as RemainingValue 
FROM [GtrMaster] a WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN [InvWhControl] b WITH (NOLOCK) 
  ON (a.SourceWarehouse = b.Warehouse) 
LEFT JOIN [InvWhControl] c WITH (NOLOCK) 
  ON (a.TargetWarehouse = c.Warehouse) 
LEFT JOIN [GtrDetail] d WITH (NOLOCK) 
  ON a.GtrReference = d.GtrReference  
WHERE ( a.EntryType = 'W' OR a.EntryType = 'S' ) 
  AND a.Complete <> 'Y' AND a.GtrReference >= '' 
ORDER BY a.GtrReference
```

If you are getting more than one record returns from `GtrDetail` from this join (likely) and that isn't what you are wanting in this result set, you can move `GtrDetail` into a subquery and aggregate or distinct to a 1:1 relationship:

```
SELECT
  a.GtrReference, a.SourceWarehouse, a.TargetWarehouse, /*a.DateCreated,*/ 
  d.ExpectedDueDate, a.EntryType, a.ControlAccount, a.InitialValue,
  a.ValRecToDate, a.Operator, b.Description, c.Description,
  Convert(decimal(14,2), 
  (a.InitialValue - a.ValRecToDate)) as RemainingValue 
FROM [GtrMaster] a WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN [InvWhControl] b WITH (NOLOCK) 
  ON (a.SourceWarehouse = b.Warehouse) 
LEFT JOIN [InvWhControl] c WITH (NOLOCK) 
  ON (a.TargetWarehouse = c.Warehouse) 
LEFT JOIN 
     (
          SELECT DISTINCT GtrReference, ExpectedDueDate 
          FROM [GtrDetail]
     ) d WITH (NOLOCK) 
  ON a.GtrReference = d.GtrReference 
WHERE ( a.EntryType = 'W' OR a.EntryType = 'S' ) 
  AND a.Complete <> 'Y' AND a.GtrReference >= '' 
ORDER BY a.GtrReference
```